# Block in spawn_thread when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, carrierwave

Recently, I implemented carrierwave into my Rails project to allow image uploads (using S3 for production) and I am now having difficulty logging in to my website. One thing to note is that my website does redirect to a page that relies on carrierwave, but I am not sure if this is the problem. Here is my result when I do `heroku logs`:

```
2017-10-14T15:51:44.926999+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:556:in `deliver_mail'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.926999+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:237:in `deliver'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.926999+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:96:in `block in deliver_now'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927000+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:15:in `handle_exceptions'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927000+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-5.1.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:95:in `deliver_now'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927001+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:191:in `send_devise_notification'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927001+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:119:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927002+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:126:in `send_reconfirmation_instructions'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927002+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927003+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:260:in `block in conditional'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927003+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `block in invoke_after'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927004+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `each'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927004+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `invoke_after'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927004+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927007+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927007+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:343:in `committed!'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927008+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:86:in `commit_records'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927009+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:178:in `block in commit_transaction'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927010+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927011+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:168:in `commit_transaction'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927012+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:207:in `block in within_new_transaction'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927013+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927014+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927015+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927015+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927016+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:381:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927017+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:308:in `block in save'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927017+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927018+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:307:in `save'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927019+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:42:in `save'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927019+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/models/trackable.rb:33:in `update_tracked_fields!'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927020+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/hooks/trackable.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927021+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/hooks.rb:15:in `block in _run_callbacks'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927021+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `each'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927022+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `_run_callbacks'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927023+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:52:in `_run_callbacks'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927023+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/proxy.rb:180:in `set_user'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927024+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/proxy.rb:328:in `_perform_authentication'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927025+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/proxy.rb:128:in `authenticate!'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927025+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:17:in `create'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927026+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927027+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927031+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927032+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927033+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927033+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927040+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927041+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927041+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927042+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927043+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927044+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927044+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927045+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927046+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927046+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927047+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927048+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927048+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927049+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927051+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927051+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927050+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927052+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927053+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927053+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927054+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927054+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927055+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927056+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927059+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927060+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927060+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927061+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927062+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927062+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927063+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927064+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927065+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927064+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927066+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927066+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927068+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927069+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927070+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927071+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927071+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927072+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927073+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927073+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927074+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927075+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927076+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927075+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927077+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927077+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927079+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927078+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927080+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.927079+00:00 app[web.1]: [87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
2017-10-14T15:51:44.928319+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_in" host=listoverflow.herokuapp.com request_id=87576d97-1735-42cb-98ca-2d5e920a98cb fwd="152.23.93.32" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=595ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=http
```

I don't really have a good sense of what is going wrong here. I see that in the middle there is a problem with warden, so it could be a problem with Devise, but it could also be a problem with my carrierwave. I have a default image that it is supposed to use if there is no image, and I am not sure if this has uploaded yet. Let me know if I need to post some more code or clarify to improve this question.